# How can I let a user download a file from an s3 bucket when clicking on a button?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I am sorry if this question is straightforward, I excected to find a lot of info on it but unfortunately I have been looking since a while and cant find anything. How could I let a user download a file which is stored in an amazon s3 bucket when clicking on a button? I thought of implementing this with a lambda function with the aid of the boto3 python SDK but I am not sure if this is possible. Thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Comment: What are you requirements in terms of security? Are you okay with the file being accessible to _everyone on the Internet_ (if they know the link), or will you be authenticating the users somehow to determine whether they are entitled to access the file?

Comment: Of course taking into consideration security is really important to know, but at this point I am trying to get more familiar with aws so I mostly care about finding a way to do it @JohnRotenstein

Comment: If you do not care about security, then just make the bucket or object public and provide a link to the object in Amazon S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case you mentioned is possible . We can handle the same using couple of ways.

- We could make the s3 bucket a public readable one, which effectively make the objects available to all the users which i think is not a good approach if you think of the security scenarios.
- We can go for a pre-signed URL for which we can setup an expiration time, so that the link will gets expired after a specific time.

{

```
bucket = 'bucket_name' # name of the s3 bucket

file_key = 'file_path/file_name' # key including any folder paths

uri_duration = 10 #expiry duration in seconds. default 3600

s3Client = boto3.client('s3')

_uri = s3Client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', Params = 
{'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': file_key}, ExpiresIn = uri_duration)
```

}

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your answer! Could I ask how I could start the download after the url is generated? Is there any way to do this with lambda?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible. You can generate a pre-signed link in a manner similar to the following.

```
            url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
                ClientMethod='get_object',
                Params={
                    'Bucket': get_bucket_name(),
                    'Key': s3_key
                }
            )
```